# add project with app delegate

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to **add a dynamic horizontal scroll to a table cell.**

I found an example after searching for a while, but since the example project only was the view it was directly connected to the app delegate which contained the majority of the relevant code. Most of it within `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

Do any of you know how I am supposed to add this code to my project?

Thanks in advance, Tom

EDIT:
Here's the link to the sample project i downloaded: http://blog.sallarp.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/slidemenu.zip

Here's the youtube clip of how it's supposed to work: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFqBNXZ4SHI

EDIT 2 (New code):

"famorables" is declared with 5 one-word-strings

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyFamorablesCell";
UITableViewCell *cell;

//Create Cell
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    
}
//Create a UIScroll View
UIScrollView    *scrollview  = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 80)]; 
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 2, 80); 
scrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

float totalButtonWidth = 0.0f;
famorableArray = self.famorables;


for(int i = 0; i < [self.famorables count]; i++){

    UIButton *famorableButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [famorableButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 30.0f)];
    [famorableButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [famorableArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // Move the buttons position in the x-demension (horizontal).
    CGRect btnRect = famorableButton.frame;
    btnRect.origin.x = totalButtonWidth;
    [famorableButton setFrame:btnRect];

    // Add the button to the scrollview
    [scrollview addSubview:famorableButton];

    // Add the width of the button to the total width.
    totalButtonWidth += famorableButton.frame.size.width;

}

[cell.contentView addSubview:scrollview];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Made an edit in the original post with links

Comment: By adding the code to the app delegate in your project.

Comment: Adding something to app delegate is some time un advisable. The App delegate is not design to handle this. It may have the ability thou but it was never design for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

Okay Try this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell;

        //Create Cell
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];    
        }
     //Create a UIScroll View
     UIScrollView    scrollview  = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, (it will be the height of the Cell u want))]; 
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 2,(it will be the height of the Cell u want)); 
    scrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

/*
Now add every this u might want to add in ur Scroll view.

keep that in mind that the height and width of contentSize and ScrollView will be depandent on ur requirement

Make sure u add every thing u want in the Scroll view will be the part of Scroll View
like for label

//Add Something to Scroll View
[scrollView addSubview:label];
*/

//Add Scroll view to Cell

[cell.contentView addSubview:scrollView];
return cell;
}
```

This will Work

In case of any queries  feel free to ask

Comment: I'll be afk for a while... I'll try it later and check your answer if it works.
Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Something went wrong... I tried to do what you said plus implement the content but instead the whole table went blank...
You are supposed to have only the cell created with common identifier and nothing in it right?

Posting the code in the question post since it's too much for a comment.